# extending aspnetuserroles table to add more columns

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am using aspnet identity 3.0 in my asp.net core project. I have a school table and I want that when a user logs in then he will select a school and he may have one or more roles in that school(student, parent, teacher, admin). When he will select the school, his default role will be selected in that role.

For that I want to extend asp.netuserroles table and add two more fields ( schoolid, and defaultrole). Which classes do I need to modify and how can I access these extra fields?

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Why add new fields when you can add new roles, or claims, with those values?

Comment: i already have roles but I want to filter roles based on school and whether the role is default in school? How can I handle it using claims?

Comment: My first thought would to name the roles appropriately so you could filter them by name.

Comment: how user will be linked to school. A user can have multiple roles in same school

Comment: Identity 3.0 allows for a user to have as many roles as they need. I am thinking you would have a set of roles for each school. Changing the existing tables doesn't seem like a good idea to me. I feel like that could break something. You could try it though. Perhaps another table with what you need, and the same key as the out of the box table.

Comment: @AsifHameed, were you able to figure this out? I have the same requirements. To me it seems a bit overkill to have to add a new table that contains the 2 keys in the AspnetUserRoles table along with a third Foreign Key